# Consumer won't start until array is full

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, producer-consumer

Like the title says, I've got a problem with the consumer thread waiting until the entire array is filled until it starts consuming, then the producer wait until it's empty again, and round they go in a circle until they're finished with their loops. I have no idea why they're doing that. Be gentle, as this is a new topic for me and I'm trying to understand mutexes and conditionals.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 6
#define LOOPS 40

char buff[BUFFER_SIZE];
pthread_mutex_t buffLock=PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t emptyCond=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER, fullCond=PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int buffIndex=0;

void* Producer(){
 int i=0;
 for(i=0;i<LOOPS;i++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffLock);
    while(buffIndex==BUFFER_SIZE)
        pthread_cond_wait(&fullCond, &buffLock);

    buff[buffIndex++]=i;
    printf("Producer made: %d\n", i);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffLock);
    pthread_cond_signal(&emptyCond);
 }

pthread_exit(0);
}

void* Consumer(){
 int j=0, value=0;
 for(j=0;j<LOOPS;j++){
    pthread_mutex_lock(&buffLock);
    while(buffIndex==0)
        pthread_cond_wait(&emptyCond, &buffLock);

 value=buff[--buffIndex];
 printf("Consumer used: %d\n", value);
 pthread_mutex_unlock(&buffLock);
 pthread_cond_signal(&fullCond);
 }

pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(){
 pthread_t prodThread, consThread;

 pthread_create(&prodThread, NULL, Producer, NULL);
 pthread_create(&consThread, NULL, Consumer, NULL);

 pthread_join(prodThread, NULL);
 printf("Producer finished.\n");
 pthread_join(consThread, NULL);
 printf("Consumer finished.\n");

 return 0;

}
```

Comment: Try adding pthread_yield as the last thing in the for loops, after signal.

Comment: Why is this a problem? If you run the program enough (I did), you'll see random variation, so your assessment of the behavior is just one possible of many nondeterministic orderings, not the only one. What behavior do you expect? The condition variables only block the threads when the queue is empty or full, respective to consumer and producer but they don't guarantee alternation, if that's what you're looking for. If you wanted alternation, why bother using a buffer though? Your queue size is effectively 1 (making `BUFFER SIZE` 1 guarantees alternation).

Comment: @ggorlen I was expecting to see random numbers of productions and consumptions one after another. My goal was to block consumption if the buffer is empty and block production if the buffer is full. The rest of the time, the two threads should both be unblocked.

Comment: OK, then you're good. When I run your program, it's random. Since it's a free-for-all when the lock is released, it makes sense that the same thread might be re-scheduled and acquire it again. If you run the program multiple times, you'll see different arrangements. Try the code [here](https://repl.it/repls/SpatialSpecificConferences).

Comment: @ggorlen I ran it a couple of times to the same result before posting, but I've ran it 15 times in a row, and I did indeed start seeing random patterns. Now I feel dumb, hahah. Thanks for clearing it up anyways. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out what I did wrong.

Comment: Don't feel dumb, this is a key part of learning multithreading that's quite difficult to grasp at first. Even if you run it 1000 times and see the same results, if everything isn't locked down to make ordering deterministic, the observed output is no guarantee that it is in fact deterministic. So even if you ran it 15 times and didn't see any variation (entirely possible), the key is to actually look at the code and convince yourself one way or the other of its properties re: ordering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thesis that the producer and consumer threads alternate running `BUFFER_SIZE` times is incorrect. The program here exhibits nondeterminism, so one of many orderings are possible between producer and consumer. The way the program is written only guarantees two things:

1. If the consumer gets the lock when the buffer is empty, it will relinquish the lock and wait to be signaled by the producer.
2. If the producer gets the lock when the buffer is full, it will relinquish the lock and wait to be signaled by the consumer.

As a consequence of these two properties, it's guaranteed that the producer will always emit first and the consumer will always be the last of the two threads to print. It also guarantees that neither thread can successfully claim the lock more than `BUFFER_SIZE` times in a row.

Beyond the above two guarantees, an actual run will yield completely nodeterministic results. It just so happens that your operating system has arbitrarily decided to re-schedule the latest thread repeatedly in your observed runs. This is reasonable because your program has said to the scheduler "do whatever you want within the ordering constraints of above two rules". The OS is free to bias towards [scheduling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) the same thread to run on the CPU again if it wants; in fact, this probably makes the most sense as the thread that just ran on the CPU has its resources already loaded ([locality of reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality_of_reference)), so overhead from [context switches](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) is reduced.

While the OS may schedule the same thread repeatedly, it's also possible that, for example, the entire process is descheduled and a higher-priority process is run, potentially evicting the [working set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_set) of the first process. In this scenario, when the first process is re-scheduled, any thread may have just as good of a shot of being scheduled.

Whatever the case, whenever nondeterminism is permitted by the programmer, ordering is out of their hands and [may not appear to be random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_fallacy) for a variety of complex reasons.

As I mentioned in the comments, it's important to be able to convince yourself of the program's ordering properties without running the program. Running the program can prove that nondeterminism exists, but it cannot prove the program to be deterministic. Some multithreaded programs contain subtle scheduling bugs or race conditions that may only arise once in a trillion (or more!) runs, so there's no way to hand-check such nondeterministic programs. Luckily, this one is trivial, so it's easy to simply run it until the nondeterminism appears.

A useful tool for debugging multithreaded programs is [`sleep(1)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sleep.3.html) in `unistd.h`. This function causes the calling thread to be descheduled, perturbing the natural ordering of the program and forcing a certain ordering. This can help you prove ordering properties. For example, adding a `sleep(1)` after `pthread_cond_signal(&emptyCond);` shows that given the opportunity, the consumer will grab the lock before `BUFFER_SIZE` productions occurred in your program.

For complex programs, tools like [Cuzz](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/cuzz-concurrency-fuzzing/) exist to programmatically insert `sleep` calls to uncover ordering bugs. See [testing approach for multi-threaded software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437763/testing-approach-for-multi-threaded-software) for a variety of resources and strategies.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider whether a mutex lock is the synchronization primitive you really want.  Some alternatives you might consider are:

- Have two buffers, one being read and one being written. The producer thread always has a free buffer to update.  Both threads wait on a barrier when they are finished with the buffer they currently have, then swap which buffer is being read and which is being written.
- The writer thread manages the buffers.  It notifies the reader thread that data is ready in a new buffer by updating the pointer to the buffer (with an atomic compare-and-swap in acquire-consume memory ordering).  The reader thread notifies the writer that it is ready to receive more data by clearing the buffer pointer, which allows the writer’s CAS operation to succeed. (If there are more than two threads, this simple mechanism no longer works and there needs to be a separate count of readers, as well as some extra tag bits to prevent A-B-A bugs when the writer re-uses a buffer.)
- There is a circular buffer of atomic elements, which can be accessed individually, and the reader and writer update their current positions in shared memory.  The reader thread does not read past where he other thread has written, and the writer thread does not write past what the other thread has read.  Memory fences ensure consistency.
- The writer thread adds each chunk it writes to a wait-free list of buffers, which the reader thread consumes.